# Host key verification failed error in matlab on windows

Tags: git, ssh

I have a serious problem with this error in Matlab:

> Host key verification failed

Our team has a repository on GitLab and I was able to load this repository in my local storage, also checkout between branches is possible. However, push, pull, and fetch cannot be executed. I have already tried to update the known hosts and some other commands like ssh-keyscan which are recommended in other requests, but still, the same error appears. I would be very pleased if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: What did you do that causes this error?

Comment: >> !git pull
Host key verification failed. 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: And when i try to pull via the source control in matlab, following error occures : Unable to pull in changes: Failed to retrieve list of SSH authentication methods: Failed getting response (Error code = -1, Error class = 23)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: Note that "host key verification failed" generally means that your ssh has *already stored the host key* (because you were able to reach the GitLab machine before, successfully) and now the purportedly-same-host has a *different* key, implying that someone has hijacked your connection and is *pretending* to be the host. If you're quite certain that the old host key is *wrong*, simply remove the old host key from your ssh key records, and the next connection will be a "first" connection, which ssh will generally Trust On First Use ("TOFU").